# Push data from iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies

I should pass data from iframe's javascript to the parent page. Both parent and iframe are static (no server-side logic).

1. I tried using `window.parent.iframeData = dataToPass;` but I get the following error (at least on Google Chrome - Version 33.0.1750.152):

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "parent_domain" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "iframe_damain". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
>
> There is a new method window.postMessage in HTML5 that allows to addEventListener on one side and to postMessage from the other. Here is a nice article/example:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
>
> The problem is that it should work for IE7 and higher, Chrome, FF etc. and mobile devices.
>   So I thought even of combining of the solutions I mentioned above i.e. if there is `window.postMessage` - use it, otherwise try `window.parent.iframeData = dataToPass;`.

The question if this will cover all the browsers? Or may be there is another elegant solution?

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. To be more specific - the data I want to pass from the iframe to the parent is a specific cookie that belongs to the iframe's domain.

Comment: As the error says the page containing the iframe and the url of the iframe src need to be of the same domain protocol and port, you cannot do anything with an iframe that uses a different domain

Comment: Thank you, I understand the error message, but this is the situation - they are from different domains. Concerning "you cannot do anything with an iframe that uses a different domain" - that is not correct - look at the solutions I am talking about in my questions.

Comment: Yes i know about the postMessage api. Was meaning you cannot directly access the iframe, eg through `window.parent.whatever` or `iframe.contentWindow.whatever`. So for the older browsers neither solution will work as you cannot access iframe directly and do not have the postMessage api.